# PHP - Same post is showing instead of the next post

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 7,
            'paged' => $paged );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        $count = 0;

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
            <?php
                $count++;
                if ($count === 1) { ?>
                    <div class="column small-12 margin-bottom-small">
                        <div class="panel-brown">
                            <img src="" alt="" />
                            <h5 class="heading-white"><a href="#"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                            <div class="para-white">
                                <?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 200, '...');?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php }
                while ($count <= 2) {
                    $count++ ?>
                    <div class="column small-12 medium-6 margin-bottom-small">
                        <div class="panel-tan">
                            <h5 class="heading-white"><a href="#"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                            <div>
                                <?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 200, '...');?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php }
                while ($count <= 4) {
                    $count++ ?>
                    <div class="column small-12 medium-6 margin-bottom-small">
                        <div class="panel-tan">
                            <h5 class="heading-white"><a href="#"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                            <div>
                                <?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 200, '...');?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php }
            ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <!-- Pagination links -->
        <?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts', $wp_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
        <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?>
```

I'm struggling to understand why the if and while statements are looping the same post but directly after this line:

```
while ( have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Where I am echoing the title this shows the list of posts instead.

What I am trying to achieve here is create a different html layout for each post that is outputted in the loop.

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean to have the first statement `if $count === 1` but then later have `while $count >= 2` ? Seems like those should all be if statements. I also don't see how you are using the results of WP_Query in the main loop... probably the issue at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to loop over your query result as shown in the [WP_Query official documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Also, not sure why you would do while loops like you were inside the main post loop itself so I changed those to if statements.

Something like this is what I believe you are after:

```
<?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 7,
            'paged' => $paged );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        $count = 0;

        if(! $wp_query->have_posts())
            die('no posts!'); // ADDED - Handle this more elegantly

        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); // ADDED - Use query result object?>
            <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
            <?php
                $count++;
                if ($count === 1) { ?>
                    <div class="column small-12 margin-bottom-small">
                        <div class="panel-brown">
                            <img src="" alt="" />
                            <h5 class="heading-white"><a href="#"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                            <div class="para-white">
                                <?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 200, '...');?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php }
                if ($count <= 2) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="column small-12 medium-6 margin-bottom-small">
                        <div class="panel-tan">
                            <h5 class="heading-white"><a href="#"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                            <div>
                                <?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 200, '...');?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php }
                if  ($count <= 4) { // ADDED - Be careful, this will fire as well as the if statement above it since they are both <= 2
                    ?>
                    <div class="column small-12 medium-6 margin-bottom-small">
                        <div class="panel-tan">
                            <h5 class="heading-white"><a href="#"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                            <div>
                                <?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 200, '...');?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php }
            ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <!-- Pagination links -->
        <?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts', $wp_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
        <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?>
```

Comment: I was trying to use the while loop so I didn't have to have two if statements to reduce my code. Let me have a look to see if this solution works though. Thanks

Comment: Sorry this is still outputting the same post instead of looping through all the posts.

Comment: Ah I figured it out.

Comment: Remove the counts and only have one and I'll move accept your answer

Comment: I removed the extra count++ issues. The issue still persists of, for example, on the first iteration of the loop, all 3 if statements are true as 1 === 1, 1 <= 2, AND 1 <= 4.

Comment: You could make this quite a bit shorter just getting rid of the final if statement (or while if you are still using it) all together. There is no difference in your html markup when comparing <= 2 block to the <=4 block.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this wasn't working is because I was calling count++ in multiple places in the while loop meaning it never was on the right count. I've fixed this by putting it once outside of the if and while loops.

Thanks for your efforts guys